# prepare for segue when fetching data from firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to ios and firebase.

I have a tableview that present documents from my firestore, 
each document has a sub collection and I want to fetch it when I hit the row, and present the new data in a second tableView

Now I'm using :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier {

    case "showOptions"?:
    let selectedDishTableViewController = segue.destination as! SelectedDishViewController
    if let indexPath = tableViewDishes.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        brain.loadOptions(dish: brain.listOfDishes[indexPath.row])
        selectedDishTableViewController.dish = brain.listOfDishes[indexPath.row]
        selectedDishTableViewController.myOption = brain.myOption
        brain.myOption.removeAll()
        }
        default: break
    }
}
```

this is my brain func :

```
func loadOptions(dish:Dish) {

        db.collection("Restaurants").document("Limon").collection("Menu").document((self.sectionName!)).collection("Dishes").document(dish.DishName).collection("Options").getDocuments { [weak self](querySnapshot, error) in
            if error != nil {print(error)}
            else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    // appending the data to my Array that will be presented in the next tableView
                }
            }
        }

}
```

what happens now is that the first time I hit the row first viewdidload of the second tableview will come up because db.collection is asynced,   that results that I have to press back and then hit the same row to see the data from the first hit.

Comment: you have to reload second controller table view on main thread.

Comment: should I add a func reload data and just reload the table or should I do it in viewDidload? I'm not sure how to execute this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I managed to fix my issue future googlers , 
I added a completion handler for the db.collection , and In ViewDidApear of the second tableView I use `tableview.reloaddata()`